# Terminal/Bash session manager

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

Is there a session manager for multi-tabs bash sessions, similar to how Google Chrome manages web surfing sessions?
What I'm looking for is the ability to store and restore the shell tabs (I'm currently using GNOME as my terminal) and their history (input and output). It would also be nice if the session will be saved automatically so that if I reboot my machine I can get back to the previous session quickly.

Answer (score 1):

There is for all of your requirements (but not for saving them), and it is called `screen`.

As for saving the sessions:

- As there is only one `.bash_history` per user, it is quite hard to keep different histories, I know of no such possibility.
- A session might easily have unrestorable state, e.g. think of having an SSH connection open - it is not possible to restore it after a reboot. THis is a systematic difference between a browser session and a shell session.

Comment: There are other options besides screen. `tmux`  comes to mind as one.

Comment: @SteveV. Ofcourse there are! I prefer screen, because it is standard on all major distros and is easily directable to a virtual serial port such as from an IPMI card.